# Analytical method to compute probability of an event given other event(s)

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, stochastic-processes

Suppose event $P(H1)$ denotes the probability of getting exactly one head and $P(T1)$ denotes the probability of getting exactly one tail after tossing two fair coins simultaneously.

I am trying to compute $P(H1\cup T1)$ using PIE (principle of Inclusion-Exclusion) in the following way.

$P(H1\cup T1)=P(H1).(1-P(H1)) + P(T1).(1-P(T1)) - P(H1|T1)P(T1)$

I can compute $P(H1)$ and $P(T1)$ but I am confused on how to compute P(H1|T1). I was wondering if there is any analytical method to compute $P(H1|T1)$? I want to write a program for finding the solution of the same problem with $n$ number of coins using PIE.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$H1$, "*exactly* one head when two coins are flipped" is the event $\{HT, TH\}$.

$T1$, "*exactly* one tail when two coins are flipped" is the event $\{HT, TH\}$.

But, *wait…*, that is the exact same event!

Thus $P(H1 \cup T1) = P(H1) = \frac 2 4$, and $P(H1\mid T1) = 1$

---

However, if we move onto $n$ coin flips, let's discuss the events: $H_n =x$ and $T_n=y$, the events of tossing exactly $x$ heads in $n$ flips, or $y$ tails in $n$ flips, respectively. A slice of PIE tells us that:

$$P(H_n=x\cup T_n=y) = P(H_n=x) + P(T_n=y) - P(H_n=x\cap T_n=y)$$

Do you know how to calculate $P(H_n=x)$ and $P(T_n=y)$?

Now, $P(H_n=x\cap T_n=y) = \begin{cases} P(T_n=y) & : x+y=n \\ 0 & : \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Can you put this together?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's now much easier to code.